# How can I copy files from many subdirectories to another directory while preserving directory structure?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a directory containing many similar subdirectories
Each of these subdirectories have some files I am interested in and some that I am not.

I want to copy:

FROM:
two particular files: file1.txt file2.json  from every subdirectory

TO: a different location

But making the subdirectories in that location

For example
If I have

```
base
|_folder_00000001
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|         |_some_other_things_I_dont_need
|         |_some_other_folder_I_dont_need
|
|_folder_00000002
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|         |_some_other_things_I_dont_need
|         |_some_other_folder_I_dont_need
|
|_folder_00000003
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|         |_some_other_things_I_dont_need
|         |_some_other_folder_I_dont_need
|
|_folder_00000004
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|         |_some_other_things_I_dont_need
|         |_some_other_folder_I_dont_need
|
```

I want to copy this to another location but excluding the "some other things and folders I dont need"

```
target
|_folder_00000001
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|         
|
|_folder_00000002
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|             |
|_folder_00000003
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|             |
|_folder_00000004
|         |_-file1.txt
|         |_ file2.json
|
```

How can I do this from the bash terminal?

Comment: Please post the script you have already written. Then from there someone may be able to see what errors it may contain.

Comment: Can you say what "copy a couple of files from all directories making those directories" means?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: They did provide a clear example of desired result.  I too found that description in words to be very unclear, so it's a good thing the example is clear.  Not sure how I'd describe it concisely; perhaps "copy directory structure, keeping only some of the files"?

Comment: @muru This isn't exactly the same as that other post.  That other post was just asking how to combine creating a directory to copy the source file into while copying the source file.  This post is about copying multiple files from mulitple directories into a different location, preserving the source directory structure in the new location.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks and I, too, see "copy directory structure, keeping only some of the files" as a reasonable, but not a necessary conclusion. Don't you think people whose descriptions in words seem unclear, also generally produce unclear code and that the two should normally be taken together?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Maybe I was biased by seeing answers exist to confirm my interpretation of the question, maybe even an accepted answer.  But there isn't any "code" here, just a directory structure.  And I think the only interpretation of the words that's compatible with both the words and the example is the one I and answerers took.  It's not a bad thing to ask for clarification of the wording, that the example is correct, though.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks and I see there's nothing there but a directory structure with no room any lack of clarity… and here, don't you think the very wording "|_some_other_things_I_dont_need" itself works like code? Still, I'm sorry I failed to notice how closely patterned this particular structure is, which pretty-much nullifies everything I said. Duh!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `cp` with `--parents`:

```bash
cd base
cp -v --parents */file1.txt */file2.json ../target/
```

Comment: I tried it. This is *almost* what I wanted. the only thing is that this creates base inside target. Is there a way to have all the subdirectories under target? (no base in the middle)

Comment: sure, fixed this

Comment: +1 for simplicity :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is there some pattern to the files you want to copy?

From the example, if we take the "-file1.txt" and the "file2.json" as the files you want copied to the new directory structure, it can be done this way, I should think:

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*-file1.txt" --include="*file2.json" --exclude="*" /src/dir/  /dest/dir/
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I like `rsync`, I have been extremely busy so could not try the solution, but I will.